# Implementing PrimMonad for newtype-d CatchT (ST s) stack

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I'm trying to get `renderText` from `xml-conduit` working with `ST` monad. Unfortunately, unlike `renderBytes`, it requires monad to be both `PrimMonad` and `MonadThrow`. `IO` satisfies this, but `ST` doesn't.

```
renderText :: (PrimMonad m, MonadThrow m) => RenderSettings -> ConduitT Event Text m ()
```

I managed to get it working with the `CatchT (ST s) a` stack, by defining PrimMonad instance:

`instance PrimMonad m => PrimMonad (CatchT m) where
    type PrimState (CatchT m) = PrimState m
    primitive = lift . primitive`

This is unhealthy orphan instance. I tried to wrap it into newtype, but got stuck on `PrimMonad`.

```
newtype Render a = Render { runRender :: forall s. MaybeT (ST s) a }

instance Functor Render where
    fmap f (Render m) = Render (fmap f m)

instance Applicative Render where
    pure a = Render (pure a)
    (Render f) <*> (Render v) = Render (f <*> v)

instance Monad Render where
    a >>= f = Render $ do
        v <- runRender a
        runRender (f v)

instance MonadThrow Render where
    throwM _ = Render $ MaybeT $ pure Nothing

instance PrimMonad Render where
   [???]
```

How could I define `PrimMonad` for this stack?

**Update**: for the record, here is the answer based on @luqui's idea.

```
newtype Render s a = Render { runRender :: MaybeT (ST s) a }

deriving instance Functor (Render s)
deriving instance Applicative (Render s)
deriving instance Monad (Render s)

instance MonadThrow (Render s) where
    throwM _ = Render $ MaybeT $ pure Nothing

instance PrimMonad (Render s) where
    type PrimState (Render s) = s
    primitive f = Render $ lift $ primitive f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to expose the `s` parameter:

```
newtype Render s a = Render { runRender :: MaybeT (ST s) a }
```

A `forall s. ST s a` monad looks appealing, but it is pretty useless, since (for example) `newSTRef` can't let the ref it created escape.   (Try making `STRef`s work with your monad to see the problem)

Once you expose `s` the `PrimMonad` instance should be straightforward.

Also you know about [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving), right?  You don't have to do all this work to make a newtype wrapper.

Comment: GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving doesn't work here, unfortunately. This is the first thing I tried.

`/home/blaze/dev/haskell-dbus/lib/DBus/Introspection/Render.hs:27:24: error:
    • Can't make a derived instance of ‘Applicative (Render s)’
        (even with cunning GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving):
        cannot eta-reduce the representation type enough
    • In the newtype declaration for ‘Render’
   |
27 |     deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
`

Comment: @blaze Oops!  There was a superfluous `forall` in my version of `Render`.  Corrected; now GND should work...

Comment: Yes, I found that without `forall` deriving works for Functor/Applicative/Monad, with some tricks. Had to write instances for MonadThrow and PrimMonad, though: without UndecideableInstances compiler can't reduce them enough.

Thanks for pointing out the need to expose `s`!

Comment: @blaze, what do you have against `UndecidableInstances`?

Comment: They require me to be sure about something, instead of putting the burden on the compiler. In short, I'm too lazy.